# Get & Show Values Of Multi Dimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have Some API that returning me Results in JSON Format, I successfully Converted it into Multi-Dimensional Array.

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [cdr] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-04-01 05:14:00
                    [callerid] => "ABC" <61344341227>
                    [destination] => 1604535320207
                    [description] => ABC1
                    [account] => ABC1
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [duration] => 10:57:57
                    [seconds] => 437
                    [rate] => 0.00200000
                    [total] => 0.06480000
                    [uniqueid] => 105943343
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-04-11 05:10:00
                    [callerid] => "XYZ" <61343241227>
                    [destination] => 16045353250207
                    [description] => XYZ1
                    [account] => XYZ1
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [duration] => 13:57:57
                    [seconds] => 447
                    [rate] => 0.01100000
                    [total] => 0.06411000
                    [uniqueid] => 105911143
                )
        )
)
```

Kindly Help me in Fetching Data in Rows/Columns.

I wrote Below Code But it's saying undefined offset ....

```
foreach( $curl_jason as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
    echo $value['callerid'];
}
```

Comment: In rows and columns, do you  mean a HTML table?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach( $curl_jason['cdr'] as $data)
{
  echo $data['callerid'];  // will print callerid value
}
```